# Firefox Launch fails when entering debug from Aptana

Tags: firefox

I have Aptana V3.4.0.201304151603
I have Firefox V23.01
I have Firebaug V1.12.0

When I select debug from aptana, Firefox launchs but the webpage does not display and I get an error in aptana "Launching Firefox - Internal Server" has encounters a problem. socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser and then run debug again".

I have restarted my browser, and I have restarted Aptana.

I am sure that it was working about 3 weeks ago (but it could have been on my other computer).
Any suggestions?
Lachlan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana only works with Firebug 1.8 and therefore needs to work with older Firefox versions from v19 or below. There was one suggestion on the web that Firebug 1.9 may work but I have managed to get Aptana V3.4, Firefox v18 and Firebug v1.8.4 all working together.